# Resolve Autofac service within InstancePerLifetimeScope on Owin Startup

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac, owin, startup

I cannot figure out a correct way to resolve a service via Autofac that is used **while constructing** the Owin context and also **disposed at the request end**.

Since the OwinContext is still under construction at this point, the LifetimeScope cannot be found by calling `HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetAutofacLifetimeScope()`. The OwinContext is not available here yet.

In my code the `IAdfsAuthorizationProvider` service is resolved directly at the `Container`, but isn't disposed after a request and lives much longer.

I could create a new LifeTimeScope by calling `container.BeginLifetimeScope()`, but now the LifeTime is separated of the request and will possibly resolve different instances in the same request. And there is no way to dispose the lifeTimeScope myself at the correct time.

```
    public void Configure(IAppBuilder app)
    {
         var builder = new ContainerBuilder();    
         builder.RegisterType<AdfsAuthorizationProvider>().As<IAdfsAuthorizationProvider>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

         var container = builder.Build();

         app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);

         // **Service that's not binding to the request lifetime.**
         var service = container.Resolve<IAdfsAuthorizationProvider>();

         app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
             {
                Provider = new AuthorizationServerProvider(service),
             });         
          }
```

Does anyone has a suggestion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` is a *singleton* that call methods for all requests.

This class has not been designed to be injected. If you want to resolve a dependency for one request you will have to resolve it manually using the owinContext provided with each method

```
public class AuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override Task GrantAuthorizationCode(
        OAuthGrantAuthorizationCodeContext context)
    {
        IAdfsAuthorizationProvider authorizationProvider =
            context.OwinContext
                   .GetAutofacLifetimeScope()
                   .Resolve<IAdfsAuthorizationProvider>();

        return base.GrantAuthorizationCode(context);
    }
}
```